# Absolutely continous probability measures and evens with full probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

If $P,Q$ are probability measure s.t. $P$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $Q$, this means that $Q(A) = 0$ implies $P(A) = 0$. Now assume that $Q(B) = 1$. Then $Q(B^c) = 0$ and this implies $P(B^c)= 0$, hence $P(B) = 1$. This seems strange, because I interpret $P \ll Q$ as "$P \leq Q$". But if $Q(B) = 1$ imples $P(B) = 1$, this interpretation makes no sense. What is wrong here?

Comment: Why would you interpret absolute continuity that way? I can't see any reason for your making that leap, except perhaps that the symbols "$\ll$" and "$\leq$" look kind of similar.

Comment: Try to give a sense of "your feeling for $P\le Q$, i.e. maybe $P(A)\le Q(A)$ for all events $A$" for instance in case of a finite probability space, $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. How can we make a choice for $P(\{k\})\le Q(\{k\})$ such that we do not have the equality all the time?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the obvious thing that is wrong is that you shouldn't interpret $P\ll Q$ as $P\leq Q$.  The symbol $P\ll Q$ means that $P$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $Q$.  This means in some sense that $P$ isn't "large" relative to $Q$, but it does not imply that $P\leq Q$ in any obvious sense.  For instance, it's perfectly possible that $P\ll Q$ but $P(A)>Q(A)$ for some $A$.  (You would have a valid point if you protested that the symbol $\ll$ is at least a little misleading, but it is the standard notation.)